# Fullscreen in Action extension iOS13

Tags: ios, fullscreen, ios13, ios-extensions

I have an action extension which should modify a picture via the native Foto app. Unfortunately, with iOS13 it always opens in the new cards look and while I have tried a lot of things I could not get rid of it.
In particular, I am setting `UIRequiresFullScreen` and `NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation` to `YES` in info.plist both, in the app and the action extension, and set the bounds to the screen bounds.

In the init of the presented ViewController, I set `self.modalInPresentation` to `YES` for iOS13 and `self.modalInPopover` for

I also set `self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;`

This results in the topmost card being "fullscreen", but there is always another card visible below, and the viewController is automatically resized to a slightly smaller height to account for this card.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate the problem:
[on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVuzH.jpg)

Is there any way to show the ViewController presented by an action extension in true fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, the NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation must be an immediate child of the NSExtension key, and I had it in the wrong place. Now it works!